# Angular + Bootstrap styles break with sub-components

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap's button group, which in raw HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

This hierarchy must be strictly adhered to (ie: putting elements in between the `<labels>` will break the CSS).

In my Angular code, the buttons are quite complex and are driven via an `*ngFor`, so I've decided to extract the button component structure (ie: `<label><input></label>`) as it's own component. So my button group template looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let actionType of actionTypes">
    <ek-action-button [actionType]="actionType"></ek-action-button>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

However this breaks the CSS because the parent/child relationship changes when rendered. I've read in other questions that these kind of cases should use an attribute selector (ie: `[ek-action-button]`) but this still places an extra element in between and breaks the css.

Are there any solutions to this? How do I remove the host? I can't use an attribute selector on an ng-container.